# Can belief in reincarnation be justified using empirical evidence?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, death, belief

It's claimed in *[An Introduction to Parapsychology, 5th ed.](https://books.google.com/books?id=E3EzxyOufbgC&lpg=PP1&dq=Introduction%20to%20Parapsychology%3A&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q&f=false)*:

> The survival hypothesis concerns the notion of postmortem survival,
>   that is, that a disembodied consciousness or some such discarnate
>   element of human personality might survive bodily death at least for a
>   time.  The survival hypothesis has obvious religious connotations, but
>   these are of no concern in scientific parapsychology.

The authors claim that:

> Even if the survival hypothesis is vague, at least specific forms of it could be open to empirical evaluation.

Is it possible to use empirical evidence to build a case that reincarnation really happens?

(Note 1: This is separate from the question "can belief in reincarnation be justified in general?" See: [Ought we only form beliefs based on sufficient empirical evidence?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8463/ought-we-only-form-beliefs-based-on-sufficient-empirical-evidence))

(Note 2: This question was partially borrowed from a deleted Skeptics.SE question by [njfife](https://stackexchange.com/users/1697886/njfife?tab=accounts). My answer will be copied from there)

Comment: Of course it is open to empirical confirmation, it is just that the confirmation has not been forthcoming so far. If we could be made to remember experiences of past lives that would make it far more plausible. If, on the other hand, reincarnation is postulated to have no detectable consequences then the question becomes why bother with it at all.

Comment: @Conifold See the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Yes.  Most reincarnation theories as a hypothesis predicts there will be commonalities of personality, and some degree of memory, life/life.  If one can find such commonalities then one has provided such justification with empirical evidence.

**Longer answer**

Science is best described by Imre Lakatos' Research Programme framework.  liquisearch.com/imre_lakatos/research_programmes.

Stephenson's child memory research provides strongly suggestive evidence supporting a reincarnation worldview.

However, the scarcity of childhood past life memories, and the loss of memories as the children age, are not predicted, and both require explanation.  As the efforts to explain them are generally not themselves usefully predictive, there are aspects of Lakatosian regressivity mixed in with the progressivity that the childhood recollections provide.

Researchers casting around for other methods of probing past life memories have investigated hypnotic recall -- which has consistently produced both past life and less frequently, between life memories. Hypnotic recall provides past life memories in a majority of subjects, addressing one of the concerns over the childhood memories.  However, it does not lead to consistent interlife times, etc between researchers -- bringing the method under some suspicion. It is, however, an example of how the Reincarnation hypothesis cna be usefully extended to other aspects of memory and personality research, which is an essential requirement for it to be a Progressive Programme.

**Alternative Explanations**

As the Dunham-Quine thesis spells out, all data can be fit with multiple often contradictory models.  That the data cited to support reincarnation is potentially explainable by other means, is true of all science.  The question that is key, is a pragmatic one of whether a reincarnation hypothesis is more useful predictively than any of the other possible explanations.

The OP is a fan of Michael Sudduth, who apparently argued for five alternative explanations.  Discussing each of these briefly:

1. Children like making up stories and sometimes hit on several real facts about other people through totally random chance.

- This explanation does not predict the same results as a reincarnation hypothesis.  The accuracy of past life storytelling can be compared to accuracy of other stories, and if the first exceeds the second, then this explanation would be contra-indicated. Stevenson's studies tend to show far greater accuracy than random stories.  Also, the frequency and complexity of storytelling tend to increase as children age, but the past life memories drop off as storytelling skill grows in children.

2. Children can access the memories of relatives of a deceased person through some unknown mechanism. (Living psi)

- "Unknown mechanism" is generally an untestable hypothesis, with no predictive power.  If one proposes psi access of neighbor's memories, then the lack of proximity for most of Stephenson's cases tends to refute such a speculation.  Also the focus on a past life, and on memories, and a single individual, are also contrary to what a psi hypothesis would predict (many neighbors, mostly thinking about their current lives).

3. Memories drift around in the ether at death and sometimes fall into other people's heads totally independent of the question of survival of the soul. (René Guénon's "psychic residues")

- The "I did this", "this was mine" characteristic of Stephenson's data is not what one would expect from just inert memories.  Stephenson also traced some personality traits, and birthmarks, which both are much more consistent with a soul rather than loose memory hypothesis.

4. Stevenson was systematically deceived by his interpreters, or for some other reason didn't see what he thought he saw. (Cartesian demon)

- Great Deciever hypotheses are generally unfalsifiable. Conspiracy hypotheses are always patchable by extending the conspiracy.  This is in general a non-predictive explanatory approach.

5. Regardless of what country you're in, for some reason -- pursuit of fame, confirmation of community beliefs, etc. -- people have a strong inclination to fake reincarnation-like incidents.

- The children involved are not of an age to pursue fame.  The reduction in these claims as the children age to the point where they could more competently perform fakes, is directly contrary to a fake hypothesis inspired by either the children, or parental coaching.

Comparing a hypothesis to possible alternatives is a good application of science.  And the one with the best match to the data, and the most useful predictions, is what a good scientist should then proceed with, after that comparison.

Comment: Hi, by coincidence I recently read a critique of Sudduth's book and I essentially agree with your alternative answer now. +1

Answer (score 1):

**No**, reincarnation is not open to empirical validation:

The problem of how life after death can be scientifically studied is not a simple one. Parapsychologists believe progress can be made in a scientific fashion, but they have received doubt both from the skeptic community and from sympathetic, neutral philosophers of science. It is this latter criticism I will focus on. The remainder of this answer is an extremely brief and hopefully accurate discussion of Michael Sudduth's new book *[A Philosophical Critique of Empirical Arguments for Postmortem Survival](http://michaelsudduth.com/survival-book-abstracts-overview/)* (Palgrave Macmillan, 2016).

The example of Ian Stevenson's work on reincarnation is pretty straightforward: he proposes to simply find case studies of alleged reincarnations who possess factual information about their past lives that they couldn't have come across by normal means.  This would seem to be evidence of some kind of paranormal activity, and indeed, much of the criticism of Stevenson has focused on trying to disprove his dozens of examples.

However, what Stevenson provides is data, not a hypothesis. The "survival hypothesis," the statement "The soul survives death", does not cause us to expect any this-worldly phenomena in itself. We could be living in an orthodox Christian world where the future states of the soul do not affect us in any way. That doesn't make the claim unusual; according to the [Durhem-Quine thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhem%E2%80%93Quine_thesis), there are very few scientific claims that can be falsified by themselves. To restate Wikipedia's example, Galileo seeing rings around Jupiter could be explained by Jupiter being surrounded by a dozen small moons and thousands of tiny objects in a ring, or it could be explained by a scratch on the lens of Galileo's telescope, as one of the other intellectuals of the day suggested. So, a truer statement of Galileo's hypothesis is actually "Jupiter has rings and I can see them perfectly well through my telescope". The second half of this is called an auxiliary hypothesis. It's not essential to the main hypothesis but we need it to get from the data we currently have to the main hypothesis.

Similarly, the survival hypothesis in a more testable form must make more specific claims that cause us to expect data, like "The soul survives death and goes to Heaven, and people can experience this themselves through near death experiences," or perhaps "The soul survives death, reincarnates sometimes on Earth, and retains at least some of its memories, and we can confirm this and rule out cold reading through carefully controlled interviews." The latter is closer to Stevenson's actual view.

But we are not done with auxiliary hypotheses yet, because at some point they lose explanatory power. For example, if Stevenson were to narrow down his claim to "I myself spoke to a reincarnated person once, in a unique event that cannot be duplicated," that's not particularly helpful for our lives. In the more general form he gives in his books, Stevenson's claims can be explained in all sorts of other ways:

1. Children like making up stories and sometimes hit on several real facts about other people through totally random chance.
2. Children can access the memories of relatives of a deceased person through some unknown mechanism. (Living psi)
3. Memories drift around in the ether at death and sometimes fall into other people's heads totally independent of the question of survival of the soul. (René Guénon's "psychic residues")
4. Stevenson was systematically deceived by his interpreters, or for some other reason didn't see what he thought he saw. (Cartesian demon)
5. Regardless of what country you're in, for some reason -- pursuit of fame, confirmation of community beliefs, etc. -- people have a strong inclination to fake reincarnation-like incidents.

None of these alternative explanations actually falsify the claim "The soul survives death, reincarnates sometimes on Earth, and retains at least some of its memories, and we can confirm this and rule out cold reading through carefully controlled interviews." They just tell us we haven't truly tested it yet.

But alas, that tells us that we need *additional* auxiliary hypotheses which reduce the explanatory power of the survival hypothesis so much that there's no particular reason to accept it as an explanation of Stevenson's data over any of the other hypotheses. In particular the living psi hypothesis would seem to cover any anomalous data that could possibly be claimed to support the survival hypothesis. So according to Michael Sudduth's book, the argument that "the soul survives death" necessarily has no explanatory power, regardless of the more specific data it is meant to analyze, or the specific test meant to prove or disprove it. There is no way to state it in a way that becomes scientifically valuable.

Sudduth concludes that the survival hypothesis is not a scientific hypothesis, meaning that it can't be evaluated empirically. This is the problem with much of parapsychology: experiments may suggest to a reader that something weird is going on, but it's hard to turn "something weird" into a scientific hypothesis, especially when it's an anomaly that is not systematically reproducible and varies its nature widely between experiments. Such deficiencies reduce the explanatory power of any hypothesis significantly.

Comment: In my (lay) opinion, this answer would be much improved by inclusion of a clear, one-sentence TL;DR (perhaps with a little **boldface** to draw attention), ideally starting with “Yes, reincarnation is open to empirical validation ... “ or “No, reincarnation is not open to empirical validation ...” .

Comment: How common is it for a person to ask a question only to answer it himself on the same day?

Comment: @jeffreysbrother It is explicitly permitted. You can do this to "share your knowledge Q and A style". In that case, you're not expecting others to answer (and there's no need to wait for them to do so), since your plan was to answer yourself anyway.

Comment: +1 for the addition of the first sentence. Well done.

Comment: This answer misunderstands the consequences of the Durhem-Quine thesis, and how science can address it.  For ANY field of study, clear falsifications are nearly impossible, because of our ability construct elaborate special case explanations allowing a theory to be compatible with almost any observation.  The way science responds to this is described by Lakatos' Research Programmes.  https://www.liquisearch.com/imre_lakatos/research_programmes.

Comment: For Stephenson's research, the observations are compatible with a reincarnation framework.  They are strongly supportive of it.   As with all science, a range of alternatives can be forced to fit the data with a variety of kluge type assumptions added.  That does not make reincarnation any less justifiable empirically than any other science claim.